# Hide queries without ORM

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, database-design, orm

So I have an application where I need to save data to database, but the data structure is based on user. Basically user inserts a .csv or .txt file to my application and it generates table with data from the file. It is great and sweet, but I want to hide my queries and make them more manageable. Currently I have manager classes like:

**TableManager**

```
public static void CreateDocumentTable(string tableName, object[] values)
{
    var query = QueryManager.CreateTable(tableName, headers);
    query.Execute();
}
```

**QueryManager**

```
public static DMQuery CreateTable(string tableName, DMAttribute[] values)
{

    var query = new DMQuery() { Command = $"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {tableName} (" };
    query.Parameters = values;

    query.Command += ValuesToQuery(values);
    query.Command += ")";

    return query;

}
```

The thing is I can't use Entity Framework, because most of this is not static. Table structure changes based on csv so I never know what kind of columns I will have to take care of.

Also it is not very secure right know. I'm not looking for best security system, but just something that can hide strings like "CREATE TABLE ...."

Comment: Relational databases shouldn't have variable schema. You may want to look into using a NoSQL database.

Comment: It looks promising. I think I'll give it a try. Thanks :) Can you recommend any particular NoSql library?

Comment: @DanielMann Yet there is DDL with things like ALTER TABLE. And metadata tables that tell you about the tables. A relational database has a schema. That doesn't mean it can't change over time.

Comment: Proper software engineering says, determine the interface your users or some lower layer have access to and let them see that. In this case the user/layer thinks they are manipulating a set of tables, so what is wrong with offering CreateDocumentTable & CreateTable? Or do you mean, you want an interface with the functionality of a DBMS? (But then where did your DMQuery object come from?) PS Re "Table structure changes based on csv so I never know what kind of columns I will have to take care of." Read about metadata tables. PPS Read about (ugh) EAV and (not) using it.